# Is this Pandas 'SettingWithCopyWarning' a False Positive?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I subset to produce a new dataframe:

```
temp_df = initial_df.loc[initial_df['col'] == val]
```

And then I add columns to this dataframe, setting all values to np.nan:

```
temp_df[new_col] = np.nan
```

This triggers a 'SettingWithCopyWarning', as it should, and tells me:

```
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

However, when I do that, like so:

```
temp_df.loc[:,new_col] = np.nan
```

I still get the same warning.  In fact, I get one instance of the warning using the 1st method, but get two instances of the warning using `.loc`:

[image]

Is this warning incorrect here? I don't care that the new column I am adding doesn't make it back to the `initial_df`.  Is it a false positive?  And why are there two warnings?

Comment: Sometimes, I get confused by `pandas` warnings to, what about something like `temp_df = initial_df.loc[initial_df['col'] == val].copy(deep=True)`?

Comment: There isn't a system or language (or organism or interaction...) that exits whose warnings haven't utterly confused me at some point.

Comment: @quapka That removed the warning when using `.loc` on the column creation - wanna suggest it as a solution with an explanation why it works?  I'll be looking it up too.....

Comment: It's not a false positive. It basically says that temp_df is a slice of another dataframe and it is a copy. If you change temp_df, initial_df will not change. Yes, explicitly copying or setting `temp_df.is_copy = None` would solve the issue. The loc part is not relevant here. They put it there because this copy-view thing becomes an issue when using chained indexing.